# Update composer.json for Google APP Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Enviroment: php 7.3

I added a new package to local composer.json

How can I move the changes? gcloud app deploy seems to ignore it as the new files doesnt appear there.

Is there anything else that needs to be run in order to check the new composer.json and update it live?

Comment: Could you specify what package you're trying to install and add the contents of your *composer.json* to the question? Do you get any errors/warnings when running the `gcloud app deploy` command?

Comment: Any package i add its the same. I checked the source of the composer.js after i did gcloud deploy and it is updated, but the files of the new packages are not in vendor/

Comment: Have you added `require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` to the top of your PHP code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/specifying-dependencies):

> Composer runs automatically when you deploy a new version of your
> application. Simply add the following line to the top of your PHP
> scripts to require the **autoload.php** file:
>
> ```
> require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
> ```

Also,

> Scripts defined in your **composer.json** file will not run when Composer
> can use a cached result.
>
> By default, App Engine caches fetched dependencies to reduce build
> times. To install an uncached version of the dependency, use the
> command:
>
> ```
> gcloud beta app deploy --no-cache
> ```

Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and eventually realised I had to run:

```
composer install
```

before running

```
gcloud app deploy
```

I'm putting this answer here in case it helps someone else...

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error I have discovered that GAE will actually load your Composer resources before your entrypoint script is called, I had Composer file autoloads specified in composer.json "autoload":{"files":[...]} and I found out that those files are actually called before my call to `vendor/autoload.php` in my entrypoint script